# How to Convert this sql query into laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**select t.product_id,t.on_hand,t.created_at 
from `table` t, 
(SELECT MAX(purchase_id) as pId FROM `table` Group by product_id) tg 
where t.purchase_id = tg.pId**

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own?

Comment: I already try more than 3 days. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = DB::table('table as t')
->select('t.product_id', 't.on_hand', 't.created_at')
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT MAX(purchase_id) as pId FROM table Group by product_id) tg'), function($join) {
    $join->on('t.purchase_id', '=', 'tg.pId');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks this query work when var_dump $result but without var_dump shown ERROR."Undefined property: stdClass::$products (View: E:\Xampp\htdocs\inventory\resources\views\pages\stock.blade.php)"  Here this table has 'Relation' with "Products". And this relationship is ---"Purchase beltongs to Products"----